# Redis cache vs. using memory directly

Tags: caching, memory, redis

I have not used Redis yet, but I have heard about it and plan to try using it for caching data.

I have heard that Redis uses memory as a cache store database. What's the point of Redis, since I can use an object or dictionary to store data? Like this:

```
var cache = {
    key: {
    
    },
    key: {
    
    }
    ...
}
```

What are the advantages of using Redis?

Answer (score 336, accepted):

Redis is a *remote* data structure server. It is certainly slower than just storing the data in local memory (since it involves socket roundtrips to fetch/store the data). However, it also brings some interesting properties:

- Redis can be accessed by all the processes of your applications, possibly running on several nodes (something local memory cannot achieve).
- Redis memory storage is quite efficient, and done in a separate process. If the application runs on a platform whose memory is garbage collected (node.js, java, etc ...), it allows handling a much bigger memory cache/store. In practice, very large heaps do not perform well with garbage collected languages.
- Redis can persist the data on disk if needed.
- Redis is a bit more than a simple cache: it provides various data structures, various item eviction policies, blocking queues, pub/sub, atomicity, Lua scripting, etc ...
- Redis can replicate its activity with a master/slave mechanism in order to implement high-availability.

Basically, if you need your application to scale on several nodes sharing the same data, then something like Redis (or any other remote key/value store) will be required.

Comment: Your last point especially makes it seem like things like [Rlite](https://github.com/seppo0010/rlite) are a bit pointless - a dictionary store would be just as suitable in most use-cases where you have a single process. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. IMO the interest of Rlite is quite limited.

Comment: thanks for these hints, so Redis is great to scale but I assume in case of a simple chat'app with in average 300 - 500 object to retrieve in memor, in-memory data structure will do the job very well if not faster since thhese are little number ?

Comment: @DidierSpezia `very large heaps do not perform well with garbage collected languages` can you explain why?

Comment: @roottraveller, I believe this is because the garbage collection process generally has to interrupt the execution of your application ("stop-the-world") to free heap memory, and the larger the heap, the longer this interruption generally lasts.

Comment: can u explain point 3,its not clear," it allows handling a much bigger memory cache/store",what does this mean in this context?

Comment: It really depends on your requirements. If you need to cacheable data that needs to be kept in sync across your nodes, then Redis makes sense. However if you have cacheable data that does not need to be kept in sync across your nodes (lists of delivery options, couriers, etc...), then a standard in-memory caching mechanism is preferable. But user-data really should typically not be cached as that data can grow very quickly. In those cases Redis may be preferable.

Answer (score 16):

My team likes using serverless architecture, where each request can go to a different container. In this case Redis can play a very important role.

We can't use a simple cache in serverless because we can't be sure our request will get served by the same container where our simple cache is stored. Redis is a good solution because it stores the cache at a remote location. We can access Redis from anywhere.

Comment: That's not true, you can share your cached data though pub/sub with rabbitMQ (for instance) sending data to all services with fanout exchange.