# Filtering elements in Redis

Tags: redis

I am new to Redis, so excuse the question.

I am trying to make a list of hashes. For example (in JSON):

```
{
  userList: [ 
    { id: 1, name: 'Foo', ranking: 10 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Bar', ranking: 5 }
  ]
}
```

And then I want to:

- Retrieve all the hashes (users) that have a ranking less than 10.
- Delete all the hashes who have ranking 0.

How do you implement the last schema in Redis? Is it possible?

How do you filter the elements, and remove some of them?

Comment: Why redis? Use a real database.

Comment: If you insist on redis, you'll have to maintain secondary indexes yourself (something that databases do _for_ you). Read about sorted set methods: http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set

Comment: First of all, redis is a real database with different purposes than whatever you are referring to. I want to use redis because it adapts to my needs in this case, if you are interested in this read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477821/redis-cache-vs-using-memory-directly). Also I have already read what you mentioned, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You don't see how sorted sets help you implement this? You store rankings there, mapped to ids of your hashes. When you need to find hashes by rankings, you query sorted sets. When you add/delete a hash, you have to not forget to update sorted sets. This is called "secondary indexes" and it's a no-brainer in any database.

Answer (score 2):

> How do you implement the last schema in Redis? Is it possible?

Redis is *schema-less*. Let's call what you need a *data storage approach*.

One possible approach is using `HSET` or [`HMSET`](http://redis.io/commands/hmset) to add these JSON objects by id, where their id is the *key* and the JSON text is the *value*. We'll call this hash as `users:byid`.

This is the first part of the problem. Now you can get objects *by id*.

Now the next issue is you want to retrieve objects in a range of what you call *ranking*. In order to get this, you need to store your objects in a sorted set using `ZADD`. Sorted sets are *sorted* by score, and items are stored *with a score*. It sounds perfect for your use case!

Actually you're going to store the object ids in the whole sorted set:

`zadd users:byranking 10 1 5 2`

... where `10` is the score (i.e. your actual ranking value) and 1 the *id* and so on.

So, how you filter items by ranking? Using [`ZRANGEBYSCORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore):

- By ranking between 0 and 10, excluding 10. `zrangebyscore users:byranking 0 (10`
- By ranking between 0 and 10, including 10. `zrangebyscore users:byranking 0 10`

The so-called `ZRANGEBYSCORE` will give you the ids of retrieved users. How you get their JSON text? Using [`HMGET`](http://redis.io/commands/hmget):

```
 HMGET users:byid 1 2
```

...which will get both user with *id* `1` and `2`, if `10` ranking is inclusive.