# Windows asp .net application and Redis

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, redis

When I have a Windows server and I put the results of my most searched queries from SQL Server in a session in a .net application and compared to caching it in Redis, what is the difference or recommended way? What are the implications of putting it in a session in the application?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking 'why use Redis?' Or 'when to use Session vs when to use Redis?' Or something else?

Comment: merits or disadvantages of using session in .net to store query data and if using redis would be better for a single windows server

Answer (score 1):

You question sounds like `Session State` vs. `Redis` for storing temporary data.

They are not mutually exclusive. You store `Session State` in memory on  single server.

In multiple web servers in a web farm, we store them in `Redis`, `SQL Server` or `State Server`.

Caching is different. You could read [Redis cache vs using memory directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477821/redis-cache-vs-using-memory-directly) in SO.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I think i will try out redis for caching(even though i have a single windows server) as i want the data to be accessible by multiple users as oppossed to storing it in a session state. My data is already in an sql server, but the data volume is getting huge and slowing down my application. Thanks.