# What's the difference between Redis Session store and regular express session memory store?

Tags: express, session, redis, session-cookies, express-session

My understanding of Redis is that everything stored in RAM / memory.  This is also true for express session memory store. Since both are stored in memory, what is the difference in terms of space and time complexity?

Wouldn't both be bad to store session data in since having a lot of users will eat up memory?

Comment: You can configure the max memory of redis. The difference. If you stop the express, the session memory is cleaned, not with redis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redis cache vs using memory directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477821/redis-cache-vs-using-memory-directly)